# Eager load polymorphic association in Rails (clear code example included)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have following db (Postgresql) structure in Rails 5:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
end

class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  # position INT
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true # Book or Song
  has_one :location, through: :product
end

# Expected result
Item.includes(product: :location).order('locations.position ASC')
Item.first.location

# Actual result
# ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError (Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :product)
```

But I have trouble for referencing *Location* through polymorphic *Product*. May be I missed some options here and selected wrong DB structure? Could you advise some "Rails way" workarounds here, rather then raw sql?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your items model but polymorphic is normally set up like this:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, as: :locateable, class_name: Location
end

class Song < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, as: :locateable, class_name: Location
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locateable, polymorphic: true
end
```

But please refer to [documentation on polymorphic relation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you doing it wrong.in your code you are saying that product is going to be polymorphic but still with wrong syntax and not including that polymorphic association in other models ..check out the above answer and do check the rails official guide for further clarification.